# asp.net associate two label controls to one text box

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-interface, accessibility

I am trying to get two label controls to be associated with one text box. This way when the screen reader is in the text box it states both labels. 
The example of this is the text box label and another label on the other side of the text box with data entry format help text. 
Strangely this works else where on the site, but when I try to duplicate the control set up it still does not work. 
Anyone have any suggestions on how to do this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

```
<label>
    Text before
    <input ... />
    Text after
</label>
```

or

```
<div id="inputbefore">Text before</div>
<input aria-labelledby="inputbefore inputafter" ... />
<div id="inputafter">Text before</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I wasn't aware of the labelledby attribute. I have read some on aria. I added the attribute to the textbox to include the two label ids with a space in between the two. It still wasn't working for me. After learning of your suggestion it gave me more stuff to search for and found out that two associated control ids do not work in IE. They were perfectly in Firefox. Although, I found an article stating IE had made some fixes. [IE aria fixes article](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2014/06/aria-labelledby-aria-describedby-support-popular-windows-browsers/)